# SparkSql Aerospike java connector

Tags: java, apache-spark-sql, aerospike

I am trying to connect aerospike as the output source for the Spark SQL.
My sample code is ...

```
aggr.write().mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).format("com.aerospike.helper.java").option("aerospike.seedhost", "localhost")
                .option("aerospike.port", "3000").option("aerospike.set", "spark-test").save();
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ov7ih.png)
While execution, It throwing exception like in the image
Please, help me to resolve this issue thanks in advance.

Comment: What connector are you using? Something homegrown or is this a project with a repo you can point to?

Comment: What connector should I use for community edition

Comment: There's the old sasha-polev/aerospark project that hasn't been worked on in a long while (https://github.com/sasha-polev/aerospark). Aerospike Enterprise Edition has Aerospike Connect for Spark  (https://aerospike.com/docs/connectors/enterprise/spark/index.html)